# LinkedIn refresh token \ extend toke duration procedure

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

According to [this wonderful and very specific document](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token#): the user must be logged in and you must posses a legal access token for this user in order to achieve a successful refresh \ duration extension of the token.

To validate the token and to ask for a full authentication is the easy part, but how do I determine if the user is logged in or not?.

Moreover, what would be the correct implementation here, my original though was to refresh the token, save it onto the DB, and then to cause a full refresh of the page, this way I will not have to find myself in the state of being authenticated with an old invalid token and finding ways to replace it dynamically(of course in order to validate the old token I also need to use it).

Another approach might be to make the a request to a 3rd page that will handle the token renewal after the main page has been loaded, which is what I will try to do.